# GCDAsyncSocket - how do I write mutable data?

Tags: ios, swift, gcdasyncsocket

The documentation for `GCDAsyncSocket` says mutable data that might change should be copied before passing it to the write function.

In the following code:

```
func send(buffer: NSMutableData) {
    let bufferCopy = NSData(data: buffer)
    socket.writeData(bufferCopy, withTimeout: -1, tag: 0)
}
```

1. Is the call to `NSData` the right way to copy the buffer?
2. Will `bufferCopy` be retained in memory until `writeData` (which is `async`) finishes, or is it local to send, and destroyed when the function exits?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*1. Is the call to NSData the right way to copy the buffer?*

Yes, it will copy the bytes to a new data object

*2. Will bufferCopy be retained in memory until writeData (which is async) finishes, or is it local to send, and destroyed when the function exits?*

Yes, it will be retained until writeData finishes. Also it will get deallocated once you return from the function send as there are no any other strong references to it from outside if writeData is synchronous. If WriteData is an async call, once the call is completed the data will be released as there won't be any strong ref to it as control would have come out from both send and the WriteData async call.  So if this call is asynchronous, that means that call needs to have a strong ref to bufferCopy.

Comment: When you say "deallocated once you return from the function", which function are you referring to?

Comment: In this case the 'send' function

Comment: writeData may not finish when send is done. I didn't show it in the code sample, but writeData has an async delegate 'didWriteWithTag'. Would bufferCopy be retained until the delegate is called, or deallocated when send is done?

Comment: If the WriteData is an async call, then it should hold on to  the buffer with a strong ref. Once that is completed, there will be no strong ref any more and it will be released. Also updated the answer

Comment: The documentation for GCDAsyncSocket says writeData retains the buffer, so it sounds like the buffer will be ok for the duration of the call.